# How can I use a stack to convert numbers from base 10 to base 2 in C++?

Tags: c++, stack

I was given the task to use a stack to convert numbers from base 10 to base 2 using C++. I was given the numbers 18, 27, 71, 107 and 178. I have no idea where to start and I was just wondering if someone would be willing to help me by writing a sample code and explaining it to me.

My teacher isn't exactly the best.

Comment: Do you know how to do it iteratively?

Comment: Is the stack supposed to be for the numbers, or for the single bits of each number?

Comment: Well I suppose by searching a bit you can find many clear examples how to do that...

Comment: the stack is supposed to be for the numbers

Comment: You cannot convert a number from base 10 to base 2 because numbers don't have bases. If you have three cars, you can represent the number three as "3" (decimal), "three" (English), "11" (binary), "III" (Roman numerals), or many other ways and it's the *same number*. I'm not being pedantic, this is a critical difference because I think what you really mean is "how can I use the stack to express a number in base 2". I don't think you actually want to convert from base 10. But it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <stack>

int main(void) {
    unsigned int n;
    while(scanf("%u", &n) == 1) { // Read a number to convert
        std::stack<int> s; // Create stack. It is initialized.
        do {
            s.push(n & 1); // Push the "lowest" digit to the stack
        } while ((n >>= 1) > 0); // Proceed to next digit until the number becomes 0
        // s.top() is the highest digit here
        while (!s.empty()) { // Print the number
            printf("%d", s.top()); // Print the "highest" number here
            s.pop(); // Proceed to next digit
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's a weird mix of C++ and C.

Comment: yeah could you possibly help me with one that is just c++?

Comment: Input: `while (std::cin >> n) { ... }`. Output: `std::cout << s.top();` and `std::cout << '\n';`

Comment: This is just c++ code and it yields no errors or warnings in [g++ -pedantic-errors](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/riuxmc7DWBWmUMus).

Comment: You should clarify that the `scanf` line doesn't just "read a number", it converts from base 10.

Answer (score 1):

A number with a base can be converted to a number with another base relatively easily. In your case there are only positive numbers. So I would stick to that for the moment.

Let's take the first number 18. Consider it a loop. You use modulo the base you want to convert to. Can be applied to any base in general. A very simple outline as follows:

```
do {
  int x = abs( n % b );
  push x on stack;
} while ( n /= b );
```

Example:

```
For n=18 it be as follows:
Stack [0]        , n = 18
Stack [0,1]      , n = 9
Stack [0,1,0]    , n = 4
Stack [0,1,0,0]  , n = 2
Stack [0,1,0,0,1], n = 1
Stack [0,1,0,0,1], n = 0 <- terminates here
```

You read from the stack, popping it like on the dancefloor:

```
while (stack not empty) {
cout << stack.pop();
}
```

Will give:

```
10010
```

Which is the number 18 in binary, i.e. to base 2.

I didn't write C++ code. I believe you are able to design and write code  yourself. Others already provided code.

Comment: This doesn't convert from base 10, which is what the OP asked for. (Though it may or may not be what the OP wanted.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz not sure if I understand. you give give a number `n` in base 10 and in the stack you have the binary number representation. isn't that right?

Comment: No. When you say "a number `n` in base 10", what do you mean? Do you mean a number? Or do you mean a representation of a number in base 10? If the former, then it's not in base 10. If the latter, then you'd need something that holds a representation of a number (like, say, `std::string`), not something that holds a number (like, say, `int`).

Comment: I see. I made it simple. OP did not really give much information.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n;
    stack<int> Stack;
    int tmp;
    cout << "Put n:";
    cin>> n;
    cout << endl;
    // Push to stack
    while(n!=0)
    {
        Stack.push(n%2);
        n = n/2;
    }
    // Get back and print out
    while(Stack.size()!=0)
    {
        // get top element in the stack
        tmp = Stack.top();
        // pop it out from stack
        Stack.pop();
        cout << tmp ;
    }
    cout << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to where it would after putting in a number and after it converts it, it would let you put in another without closing the program?

Comment: you can put my code into a loop scanning input (the same as the other answers). It can help you. I'm sorry for missing you requirement :)

Comment: how would I go about putting it into a loop?

Comment: I think you should use your brain power to solve it. I can do it for you, I will modify my code but I want you to do it by yourself. It will be good for you. :)